# Case when duplicate add one more letter

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example: I have a table with these records below

```
1  A
2  A
3  B
4  C
```

...

and I need to migrate these record in to another table

```
1  AA
2  AB
3  B
4  C
...
```

Meaning if the record is duplicate, it will automatically add one more letter alphabetically.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What is the maximum of possible duplicates that you are expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

Just a slightly different approach

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (ID int,[SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'A')
,(2,'A')
,(3,'B')
,(4,'C')

Select *
       ,NewVal = concat(SomeCol,IIF(sum(1) over (partition by SomeCol)=1,'',char(64+row_number() over ( partition by SomeCol order by ID ))) )
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  SomeCol NewVal
1   A       AA
2   A       AB
3   B       B
4   C       C
```

EDIT - Requested UPDATE

```
Declare @YourTable Table (ID int,[SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'A')
,(2,'A')
,(3,'B')
,(4,'C')

Select *
       ,NewVal = concat(SomeCol,IIF(sum(1) over (partition by SomeCol)=1,'',replace(char(63+row_number() over ( partition by SomeCol order by ID )),'@','')) )
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  SomeCol NewVal
1   A       A
2   A       AA
3   B       B
4   C       C
```

Comment: hi thanks alot but is it possible to skip the 1st dublicate value ex: 1 A  A     2   A   AA

Comment: @TrietHoang Sure, but that was not the original requirements.  See EDIT - Requreded UPDATE.  Also, in the future please be more precise with your question and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

We might be able to handle this requirement with the help of a calendar table mapping secondary letters to duplicate sequence counts:

```
WITH letters AS (
    SELECT 1 AS seq, 'A' AS let UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'B' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'C' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 26, 'Z' UNION ALL
    ...
),
cte AS (
    SELECT id, let, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY let ORDER BY id) rn,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY let) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT t1.id, t1.let + CASE WHEN t1.cnt > 1 THEN t2.let ELSE '' END AS let
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN letters t2
    ON t1.id = t2.seq
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo